# ANTLR - left recursion removal assistance

Tags: java, recursion, antlr, grammar

I have this grammar that has left-recursion and I'm not understanding how I can make it non-left-recursive. It's my first time working with parsers/grammars etc so please keep any explanation simple.

```
msg: IDENTIFIER
   | IDENTIFIER LBRACKET msg RBRACKET
   | msg COMMA message
   | LBRACE msg RBRACE LBRACE atom RBRACE
   | msg XOR msg
   | msg PERCENT IDENTIFIER
   | IDENTIFIER PERCENT msg
   | LBRACKET msg RBRACKET
   ;

atom: IDENTIFIER
    | fn_app
    ;

fn_app: IDENTIFIER LBRACKET IDENTIFIER (COMMA IDENTIFIER)* RBRACKET;
```

I tried on my own, but ANTLR still says there's recursion and I cannot understand why.

ANTLR says this:

```
[fatal] rule msg_contents has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,3.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.
```

My attempt:

```
msg_contents: msg_part
            | msg_part XOR msg_part
            | msg_part PERCENT msg_part
            ;

msg_part : IDENTIFIER
         | IDENTIFIER LBRACKET msg_part RBRACKET
         | LBRACE msg_part RBRACE LBRACE atom RBRACE
         | IDENTIFIER PERCENT msg_part
         | LBRACKET msg_part RBRACKET
         ;
```

Please help. Thank you!

P.s. If possible, please provide an explanation or steps about how you remove the recursion from such a grammar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, when removing immediate left recursion (as you are facing it), you factor out the recursive reference and replace

```
   A ::= A x
       | y
```

by

```
   A ::= y x*
```

In your case this means factoring to

```
msg: msg ( COMMA message
         | XOR msg
         | PERCENT IDENTIFIER
         )
   | ( IDENTIFIER
     | IDENTIFIER LBRACKET msg RBRACKET
     | LBRACE msg RBRACE LBRACE atom RBRACE
     | IDENTIFIER PERCENT msg
     | LBRACKET msg RBRACKET
     )
   ;
```

and replacing to

```
msg: ( IDENTIFIER
     | IDENTIFIER LBRACKET msg RBRACKET
     | LBRACE msg RBRACE LBRACE atom RBRACE
     | IDENTIFIER PERCENT msg
     | LBRACKET msg RBRACKET
     )
     ( COMMA message
     | XOR msg
     | PERCENT IDENTIFIER
     )*
     ;
```

The [Wikipedia entry on left recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_immediate_left_recursion) explains it quite nicely.

The ANTLR message that you got is not related to left recursion. It says that ANTLR cannot decide between the alternatives of

```
msg_contents: msg_part
            | msg_part XOR msg_part
            | msg_part PERCENT msg_part
            ;
```

because all begin with `msg_part`, which is recursive, and thus not regular, as required for LL(*) lookahead. However that could be solved left factoring. Also note that your attempt omitted the `COMMA` variant.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I was also able to understand that A = Ax | y thing that I couldn't understand from Wikipedia. Now I know how it's applied.